# MapTileLayer using custom tile sizes

Tags: windows-phone

As far as I understand, your overlay tiles have to be of the same size as the Bing tiles. What if the tiles I whant to render on top of Bing do not match the sizes of Bing tiles?

For example, on zoom level 1 there are 4 Bing tiles with size 256x256 pixels each. So the map in total has a size of 512x512 pixels. On top of this map I'd like to render tiles from another map which are of size 481x326. This other map has 9 tiles in total.

So, Bing will trigger a render of its tile (0,0). The LocationRectTilesSource will analyze the tile coordinates, the zoom level and determine the Uri of the image to use. The problem is that for one Bing tile I don't have one overlay tile image but many (4 using the example above).

It seems that I should have to prepare my overlay tiles to match the pattern of Bing. This way there would be a 1 to 1 relation. Is there a way of avoiding this step and use my custom tiles?

Thanks!